# Codeigniter not showing correct insert_id while inserting 3 tables with single query

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this app where I insert data into 3 tables with one single query but it looks like second table is getting the correct id inherited from first table but third table always shows one less (id-1). E.g. if id is 372, it will show 371.

Please suggest

Model:

```
function insert_property_details($data) {

    // First Table
    $insert_property_in_database=array(
       'v_item_title'   => $this->input->post('v_item_title'),
       'v_item_category'=> $this->input->post('v_item_category'),
       'v_num_rooms'    => $this->input->post('v_num_rooms'),
       );
       $query=$this->db->insert('vbc_vacation_item_attri',$insert_property_in_database);

    // Second Amenity table
    $insert_property_amenities=array(
       'v_ref_id'       => $this->db->insert_id(),
       'v_aircondition' => $this->input->post('v_aircondition'),
       'v_handy'        => $this->input->post('v_handy'),
       );
       $query=$this->db->insert('vbc_property_amenities',$insert_property_amenities);

    // Third Image table
    $insert_images = array(
        'property_images' => $data['uploadedimage'],
        'property_ref_id'   => $this->db->insert_id(),
        );
        $this->db->insert('vbc_property_images', $insert_images);

        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Comment: insert_id() returns the id of the **LAST** performed insert. that means your 2nd table gets the id created by the 1st insert, and your 3rd insert is getting the ID performed by the **SECOND** insert. if the 3rd table needs to use the first table's id, then you'd have to do `$t1_id = $this->db->insert_id()` and use `$t1_id` instead for the 2nd and 3rd calls.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, Yes it worked with those changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only have one `insert_id()` and then use a variable to get it also no need for `$query` for insert.

Model:

```
function insert_property_details($data) {

    // First Table

    $insert_property_in_database = array(
        'v_item_title' => $this->input->post('v_item_title'),
        'v_item_category'=> $this->input->post('v_item_category'),
        'v_num_rooms' => $this->input->post('v_num_rooms'),
    );

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->insert('vbc_vacation_item_attri',$insert_property_in_database);

    // Or have the id just below first insert
    // $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    // Second Amenity table

    $insert_property_amenities = array(
        'v_ref_id' => $id,
        'v_aircondition' => $this->input->post('v_aircondition'),
        'v_handy' => $this->input->post('v_handy'),
    );

    $this->db->insert('vbc_property_amenities',$insert_property_amenities);

    // Third Image table

    $insert_images = array(
        'property_images' => $data['uploadedimage'],
        'property_ref_id'=> $id,
    );

    $this->db->insert('vbc_property_images', $insert_images);
}
```